# Java Scheduled Executor Service wait all threads complete

Tags: java, service, executor

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{Runnable autoUpdate = new autoUpdateWork(i);
ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleAtFixedRate = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(autoUpdate, 0, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
if (scheduleAtFixedRate != null)
    {    
        while(!scheduleAtFixedRate.isDone())
        //wait...
    }
//PointA :until all threads are finished, do sth, then invoke the scheduled task with 60 sec interval    again.
```

So far the above is my code. But seems it would never get to PointA.. Please help, thanks!

Comment: finally did it in the way of wrapping the runnable class with another outer runnable class. Anyway, thanks for helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of doing

```
if (scheduleAtFixedRate != null)
{    
    while(!scheduleAtFixedRate.isDone())
    //wait...
}
```

In your Runnable class add a volatile variable like below.

```
public  volatile boolean isRunning = false;
```

and once your thread completes the work, change it to true and in your checking part put like .

```
while(!autoUpdate.isRunning);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried your code but the schedule seems to be all terminated immediately?